# Migrating asp.net website from IIS6 to IIS7 - Debugging differences

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I recently migrated an application from IIS6 to IIS7.  I've noticed two distinct differences and was wondering if someone could shed some light on them:

When I attach the debugger to the w3wp.exe process, it seems that the request times out much quicker than it did with XP.  I set the executionTimeout attribute of the httpRuntime element in the web.config to be 864000 in hopes that it would execute for a very long time.  This has not helped and I'm open to suggestions for how to allow for longer debugging sessions.

Comment: I probably should have split this up into two questions.  Both Rick and technophile have correct answers.

Comment: The 2nd question was moved to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760542/asp-net-forms-authentication-cookie-not-honoring-timeout-with-iis7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1, you need to turn off the "Ping Enabled" setting in the Advanced Properties for the application pool. Otherwise, if you sit on a breakpoint, the process can't respond to IIS's ping and it believes the process is hung and recycles the app pool. You probably want to turn off the idle timeout as well.

For #2, I'm not sure; even with Rick's answer it sounds like it should be working as you intend.

Answer (score 2):

Read up on the [Sliding Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61%28VS.71%29.aspx).  It doesn't work the way you would think:

> Specifies the amount of time, in
>   integer minutes, after which the
>   cookie expires. The default value is
>   30. If the SlidingExpiration attribute is true, the timeout attribute is a
>   sliding value, expiring at the
>   specified number of minutes after the
>   time the last request was received.
>   To prevent compromised performance, and to avoid multiple browser warnings
>   for users that have cookie warnings
>   turned on, **the cookie is updated when
>   more than half the specified time has
>   elapsed.** This might result in a loss
>   of precision. Persistent cookies do
>   not time out.

[Forms Authentication and Sliding Timeout](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2004/10/11/241080.aspx)