# ASP.net security questions "Authorization" and ".ASPXAUTH" cookies

Tags: asp.net, security

I have couple questions about security in ASP.net and in general.

1. Where are stored "Authorization" cookies? When I logined in the system and then decided to logout I suppose for this enough to delete cookies from my browser but this not work. Then I rethink that these cookies is supplied from browser stored passwords, but wrong again, since I don't see login/password info for my site there.
   And since "Authorization" cookie is always returned in response for 401 code, user stays always logined in the system and I can't understand how to logout.
2. The timeout for ".ASPXAUTH" - 30 min is recommended, and then cookie expired. Though I login, then after recommended 30 minutes I need to login again (even with sliding property to true, I can just leave a page for more than 30 minutes). But when I login to the most of the sites (such as stackoverflow for example), I can enter here again without logining even after week delay. How it is implemented, is that sites just set timeout for much bigger timespan or there is some other techniques?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Answer to question 1:

Use FormsAuthentication.Signout(); to logout. This will delete the authentication cookie. The authentication cookie is stored in the http-request and in the response as every other cookie.

Rergarding your 2nd question: Your cookie should expire after 2880 minutes. I don't know why it expires after 30 minutes in your case. Also the sliding expiration normally works. Could your browser settings have some influence? Another possiblility could be that the Visual Studio internal web server does not behave like a real web server. Try your settings on IIS.

EDIT:
I think the answer to your 2nd question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760542/asp-net-forms-authentication-cookie-not-honoring-timeout-with-iis7)

Comment: Thanks for response!

1st: can you please explain how it works internally, I mean where Authetication cookie is actually reside?
2nd: <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="https://localhost:44301/Service.svc" timeout="2880" slidingExpiration="true" requireSSL="true">
      </forms>
    </authentication>

Comment: Is your login form really a WCF service?

Comment: yes, but using Forms authentication. But I think context here doesn't matter, the point is ASP Forms authentication

Comment: I just wonder how that works. loginUrl is the URL of the asp.net page to where the user is redirected when he is not authenticated. A service normally has no user interface.

Comment: The purpose of redirection here, is switch to ssl