# ASP.NET Forms authentication timeout expires too soon

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, authentication

I have read a lot of examples but I dont know why my code doesn't work. This is a part of my `web.config` code in my `ASP.NET` project:

```
  <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Panel/Login" timeout="525600" slidingExpiration="true" />
      </authentication>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
  </system.web>
```

The problem is that when I login, after a few minutes of inactivity when I try to request something I'm navigated to the Login page. This happens even if I set persistent cookie in my Login page!

I've tried to increase and decrease `timeout` attribute.

I've tried `slidingExpiration` attribute.

I've tried `cookieless` attribute.

None of them works!

I use this code in Login page:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Username.Text, Remember_Me.Checked);
```

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to add machineKey to your code :

```
<machineKey validationKey=”AutoGenerate”
```

You can see more detailed information here :

http://blog.falafel.com/asp-net-forms-authentication-times-out-on-a-shared-host/

Or this maybe in help :

[Asp.net forms authentication cookie not honoring timeout with IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760542/asp-net-forms-authentication-cookie-not-honoring-timeout-with-iis7)

Comment: I would agree on the machinekey. If the app pool recycles a new machinekey is generated. Using a set machinekey may help but there could be another problem if the app pool is recycling in a short amount of time. Are you also storing anything in session state that could be large or working with any unmanaged code that could be eating resources?

Comment: Thanx a lot! it helped me. But now the problem is when I check the "Remember Me" checkbox, I still have the mentioned time in timeout attribute. I mean now there is no difference if I check the checkbox or not. What should I do???

Comment: well that may help : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/friis/archive/2010/08/18/remember-me-checkbox-does-not-work-with-forms-authentication.aspx

Comment: Now I'll set FormsAuthenticationTicket if user has checked the "remember me" checkbox and I'll use FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie if he/she hasn't. You helped me a lot. Thank u :)