# ASP.Net Forms Authentication - Login times out after 5-10 minutes

Tags: asp.net, authentication, session, session-cookies

I've got an app in MVC5 which uses forms authentication. Since rolling it out to a server, after being logged in for 5-10 minutes you are logged out; I would like the login to remain for minimum 1 day.

I suspect this is because the app pool is recycled after 5 minutes of inactivity; unfortunately this is a feature of our hosting and I have no control over it.

I've tried a number of things to work around this:

- Set persistent to true on the login call, i.e. forcing it to
  "Remember Me".
- Set the session state to use a SQL Server database,
  with a timeout of 1440.
- Set timeout under  to 1440 in the web.config.
- Forced all three computers that use the site to trust the site in the browser, to make sure the cookie isn't being destroyed.
- Set Session.Timeout to 1440 in global.asax.cs (probably redundant when this is also set in web.config)

A few points of background:

- The site uses autofac to instantiate the database connection, which interacts with OWIN.
- Pretty much everything else regarding the login comes from a standard visual studio setup, meaning I created a new web project and set authentication to forms.
- The cookie is still there after being sent to the login screen.
- The session is still there (in the database) after being sent to the login screen.

Does anyone know how I might fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

[Asp.net forms authentication cookie not honoring timeout with IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760542/asp-net-forms-authentication-cookie-not-honoring-timeout-with-iis7?rq=1)

For anyone wondering, the fix here appears to have done the trick. Specifically, setting the machineKey in the web.config.